# variable size array matching

Tags: python, arrays, list, python-3.x

I have a data file which is sorted based on the first column

```
1 3 2
3 6
4 8 5 6 2
4 9
5 2 2
```

There is a key with three items, say `seen = [4 8 5]` that I want to search in the above array. Since some of the rows have less than three columns, the following code fails to compare and I know that

```
take = [row for row in lines if row[0] == seen[0] and row[1] == seen[1] and row[2] == seen[2]]
```

So what should I do for the rows that have less than three columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using slice, you don't need to check all 3 items manually and check length:

```
take = [row for row in lines if row[:3] == seen]
```

Comment: A nice opportunity for a handy `filter` expression: `take = filter(lambda row: row[:3] == seen, lines)`.

Comment: @Falko, In Python 3.x, you need to wrap it with `list` to get a list object because the `filter` returns an iterator instead of a list: `take = list(filter(lambda row: row[:3] == seen, lines))`

Answer (score 1):

Add a guard (`len(row) >= 3`):

```
take = [row for row in lines if len(row) >= 3 and row[0] == seen[0] and row[1] == seen[1] and row[2] == seen[2]]
```

This will short-circuit (and fail) the check if the row doesn't have enough elements