# Comparing a list with file rows

Tags: list, file, python-3.x

I am trying to compare a list with the lines that are read from a text file. I asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31770724/variable-size-array-matching), but that does not work since the data are read from file and each line is splitted.

Assme a data file looks like

```
2 3 5
1 2 7 8 2
1 4 3 4 6
```

I read that file using

```
fs = open("in.txt")
lines = [line.split() for line in fs if line.strip()]
```

Then, I define a list like this

```
seen = []
seen.append(1)
seen.append(2)
```

Next, I compare the queue with each line to finda match using

```
take = [row for row in lines if row[:2] == seen]
```

However, take is empty although it should be 1 2 7 8 2. The complete code is

```
fs = open("in.txt")
lines = [line.split() for line in fs if line.strip()]
seen = []
seen.append(1)
seen.append(2)

take = [row for row in lines if row[:2] == seen]
if len(take) != 0:
    print(take)
else:
    print("no match")
```

As I debug the program I see that each line of the file is presented like `['1', '2', '7', '8', '2']` while the `seen` list looks like `[1 2]`. How can I fix that?

Comment: Is your question really just *"how can I convert strings to numbers?"*, because that's been answered more than once before... Python is dynamically **but strongly** typed, `1 != '1'`!

Comment: Do you mean that my question is actually summarized to "how can I convert strings to numbers?" :D

Comment: Yep, or vice versa; `row[:2] == seen` will never be true as long as `row` contains strings but `seen` contains integers.

Comment: Excuse me, I tried `lines = [[int(i) for i in line.split()] for line in fs if line.strip()]` to convert each symbol in a row to an integer number, but still the branch goes to "no match"

Comment: Well `[1, 2, 3][:2] == [1, 2]` evaluates to `True`, so you should probably check what's in `seen` and `lines`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are reading the input file in a list, the content of the list is strings.. You have only to type cast each entry...

```
fs = open("in.txt")
lines = [[int(strNumber) for strNumber in line.split()] for line in fs if line.strip()]
```

The rest should be similar..
Perhaps you should also handle exception if the content is not convertable to a integer..

Comment: This is what I'd have guessed. The OP claims in the comments to have tried this without success, though.

Comment: And I would expect it to, all I'm telling you is what the OP has said above.

Comment: Yes it is working. There was a problem with my read input file which is now fixed. Thanks